# Prisma: very slow nested writes when connecting with remote DB Postrgsql on AWS

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I am writing a very basic query with prisma:

```js
async createContext(contextData: CreateContextDto): Promise<ContextRO> {
    const statements = contextData.body
      .split('\n')
      .filter((statement) => statement !== '')
      .map((statement) => ({ content: statement }));
    const context = await this.prisma.context.create({
      data: {
        contextName: contextData.name,
        userId: contextData.user,
        statements: {
          create: statements,
        },
      },
      include: {
        statements: true,
      },
    });

    return { context };
```

With local PostgreSQL the same query takes around 4s. When connecting to PostgreSQL on AWS it goes up to 90 seconds.

Any ideas why is it taking so long?

Please find an [example repo](https://github.com/monapasan/prisma-slow-request-to-remote-db) reproducing this issue.

And [cli output](https://gist.github.com/monapasan/fa101284270e5e2c522d75b635703872) when running Prisma with 'DEBUG=*'

ps. if I run the same query with typeorm with PostgreSQL on aws, it takes  1-2 seconds so it is not a problem with deployment. (check branch "typeorm" to see the comparison)

Comment: you are using promise , but you didn't resolve you did return !

Comment: Could you try enabling the ```nApi``` and seeing if there are any changes? You can learn how to do this for your version of prisma [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-engines/query-engine#configuring-the-query-engine). If this doesn't solve the issue, could you log your Prisma events and provide what happens when you run the query?  You can set the env variable ```export DEBUG="*"``` to do this, as described in the [debugging article](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/debugging) of the docs.

Comment: @AhmedAlSaeed I am not sure I understand what you referring here. The function is supposed to return Promise here.

Comment: @TasinIshmam Thanks for your advice! As I am running the latest prisma version I believe the nApi is enabled by default.
I also update my question with debug output and repo example

Comment: Thanks, this is a really detailed response. If I'm not mistaken, the logs you have provided are for running the query locally. Would it be possible to kindly provide the same for running it on the AWS instance? (As the logs provide information on the time taken for each step, it would be helpful to resolve what is taking so long).

Comment: @TasinIshmam hmm, I've tried to use "debug=*" and also "debug=prisma*" but the output is the same as I've posted in the gist above.
Last message is from engine: ` prisma:client:libraryEngine sending request, this.libraryStarted: true +13s`.
I don't see how I get logs on time for each step. I will try to look into this a bit more

Comment: You might consider adding your own debug logging to see what SQL query(ies) are actually being generated from your Prisma query and the query duration.  You can hook the 'query' event in Prisma to do this.  Here's some code:


      prisma.$on<'query'>('query', (e: any) => {
        const msg = `\nBegin query (Prisma): -----\n  Query: ${e.query}\n  Parameters:${e.params}\n  Duration: ${e.duration}ms\nEnd query (Prisma): -----\n`
        console.debug(msg);
      })

Comment: @OlegYarin please feel free to create a [bug report](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new/choose) with the information you have provided and we can look into this more closely!

Comment: @TasinIshmam Thanks for you suggestions. I am looking into it myself now with debugging options you recommended. I also created a [bug](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/9612) in the Prisma repo a while ago but unfortunately haven't gotten any responses yet.
I am experiencing the same issue with mongoDB and Prisma. Extremely slow writes to the remote Atlas DB.

Comment: @OlegYarin Hey, really sorry about this. Let me see if I can have someone take a look!

Comment: @OlegYarin I updated this answer with the solution we discussed on github, in case it helps others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `createMany` instead of `create`. `create` uses a separate insert under the hood for every single nested write. If there are a lot of `statement`s connected to one `context` record, you're making a lot of separate queries to the remote database, which is quite slow.

What you can do is:

1. Use `create` to create one `context` record, without the nested `statement` records.
2. Use a separate `createMany` for the `statement` records, manually specifying the `contextId` using the `id` you got from step 1.

You could also wrap queries 1 and 2 in a [transaction](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/prisma-client-transactions-guide), if you think that's appropriate.